Why can't a packed struct contain array?
This is what I have written:
  typedef struct packed {
    logic [7:0]  marker [2];          // BYTE marker[2] -> Array of 2 bytes
    logic [15:0] length;             // WORD length -> 2 bytes (16 bits)
    logic [7:0]  jfif [5];            // BYTE jfif[5] -> Array of 5 bytes
    logic [7:0]  major_vid;           // BYTE major_vid -> 1 byte (8 bits)
    logic [7:0]  minor_vid;           // BYTE minor_vid -> 1 byte (8 bits)
    logic [7:0]  pixel_density_unit;  // BYTE pixel_density_unit -> 1 byte (8 bits)
    logic [15:0] x_density;          // WORD x_density -> 2 bytes (16 bits)
    logic [15:0] y_density;          // WORD y_density -> 2 bytes (16 bits)
    logic [7:0]  x_thumbnail;         // BYTE x_thumbnail -> 1 byte (8 bits)
    logic [7:0]  y_thumbnail;         // BYTE y_thumbnail -> 1 byte (8 bits)
  } jm_app0_t;

I get these errors:
Field 'marker' in packed struct is not packed.
Field 'jfif' in packed struct is not packed.

What does it mean that it is not packed? It is a fixed size. How come that is not "packed"?

QuestaSim, an old version.

This is a type safety feature. "packed" data types are used to represent integral values. This means you can do things on the value as a whole like compare them with relations operators like less than/greater than, or add them together. Unpacked datatypes are aggragates of other types, not necessarily other packed types. If you were to allow unpacked types inside a packed type, that would be breaking type safety. It's not a technical limitation.

Thanks, I have posted a question about writing into binary file. I am trying to write a packed struct data into binary file but it is not working. I am not sure what format string to use. I shall be grateful if you could share some thoughts on it.
